# convert base64 string to image in wcf service c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have web application which will convert image to base64 string. pass it to WCF service and serivce methods will convert the string back to `png` image.

Client Side (Convert Image to Base 64)

```
public static string ImageToBase64(string path)
{
    using (Image image = Image.FromFile(path))
    {
        using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
            byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
}
```

WCF Serive Method

```
CommonDataManager.Base64ToImage(designImage).Save(designQuotePath + "/" + "Request_Quote_" + objQuote.Customer_Id.ToString(), ImageFormat.Png);

public static Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
    Image image = null;
    try
    {                
        byte[] imageBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {                    
            image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogManager.LogException(ex, "Base64ToImage");
    }
    return image;
}
```

Issues :

- It is giving output as normal file not `.png` file.
- Is there any special things need to be checked before sending base64 string to wcf service method as parameter ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is _normal_ file? Did you try to add file extension?

Comment: @RomanDibikhin Yes, when i give extension as `.png` it works. Then why not from code ?

Comment: MSDN has an example showing you need to add extension manually. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the extension. Update this:

```
    CommonDataManager.Base64ToImage(designImage).Save(designQuotePath + "/" + 
"Request_Quote_" + objQuote.Customer_Id.ToString(), ImageFormat.Png);
```

To

```
   CommonDataManager.Base64ToImage(designImage).Save(designQuotePath + "/" + 
"Request_Quote_" + objQuote.Customer_Id.ToString() + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
```